# ¿Como borrar imagen de servidor PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Buenas tardes.. Tengo una duda.. Cuando edito informacion a partir de un formulario, en este caso cambio una foto de perfil aun queda en el servidor la imagen que se reemplazo.. que metodo puedo utilizar para borrar esa imagen que ya no tiene funcion?
Probe con unlink() pero quizas no es lo mas conveniente o no lo hice de la mejor forma. No borra la imagen y tambien no envia $respuesta. El codigo funciona, la imagen cambia. Dejo codigo. Gracias!

$imagenActual es igual al src de img que se visualiza en el momento de editar por ejemplo "imagenes/perfiles/97/rostro.jpg"

```
if($_POST["perfil"] == "editar"){
        // die(json_encode($_POST));
        
        try{
            include "conexion.php";
            if($nombre_imagen !== ""){
                unlink($imagenActual);
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE perfiles SET nombre_perfil=?,usuario_perfil=?,biografia_perfil=?,sexo_perfil=?,image=? WHERE cuenta_id=?");
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $nombre, $usuario, $biografia, $sexo, $imagen_url, $id);
            }else{
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE perfiles SET nombre_perfil=?,usuario_perfil=?,biografia_perfil=?,sexo_perfil=? WHERE cuenta_id=?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $nombre, $usuario, $biografia, $sexo, $id);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $registros = $stmt->affected_rows;
            if($registros > 0){
                // Si hay un campo afectado
                $respuesta = array(
                    "respuesta"=>"exito",
                    "datos"=>$id
                );
            }else{
                $respuesta = array(
                    "respuesta"=>"error"
                );
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
        die(json_encode($respuesta));
    }
```

Comment: Antes de borrar debes siempre verificar primero que el archivo existe, por ejemplo: `if (file_exists($imagenActual)) { $outPut= unlink($imagenActual); } else { $outPut="No existe"; } var_dump($outPut);` Esto deberá mostrarte `true` o el mensaje `No existe` o `false` en caso de que `unlink` falle por algún motivo, como permisos de lectura/escritura sobre el archivo (considera verificar también los permisos para escribir un código robusto).

Comment: @Cedano Gracias, pude solucionarlo: Estaba pasando mal escrito el string, le faltaba una "/" jajaj..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de borrar debes siempre verificar primero que el archivo existe.

PHP tiene la función [`is_writable()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-writable.php), que sirve para saber todo lo que necesitas antes de borrar un archivo:

1. Que éste exista
2. Que el usuario tenga permiso de escritura con respecto al archivo (si no tiene permiso de escritura no podrá borrarlo, como es lógico).

Con algo así controlarías el flujo de tu código, informando al usuario de lo ocurrido.

```
if ( is_writable($imagenActual) ) { 
    $outPut= unlink($imagenActual); 
} else { 
    $outPut="No existe o no tienes permisos de escritura"; 
} 
# Prueba
var_dump($outPut);
```

Esto deberá mostrarte `true` o el mensaje `No existe o no tienes permisos de escritura` o `false` en caso de que unlink falle por algún otro motivo distinto.